# I need to capture all the webelements in a page

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing lots of issues while we are executing the same script from instance to instance. [All the webelement properties getting changed from one instance to another]

Is there any solution to capture all the webelements in a page and pass in the script.

Please give me a solution to resolve this issue.

Comment: You want to text of all elements

Comment: yes, and store it in all variables and if any changes in the webelement properties, i has to pass th script

Answer (score 0):

Selenium requires a locator of an element. If the properties are changing but the location is same on the page then you can use absolute XPath. It is not recommended as if any of the element location change by developers then you need to maintain your locator again but that is the only solution you have currently

You can use absolute path like an example below

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/button
```

And the element which you can found by text like

```
//a[contains(.,'Next')]
```

Comment: For an example if you are using client side tech like AngularJS. In this situation id's and other property differs from instance to instance. Exmaple in QA env the id of login text let say login_1 but in UAT you will find it login_21 .. so you can't use id eventhough they are present because js will change the id's dynamically on page. In that case you can use absolute xpath as per the code will be same just the properties is different

Comment: Ok @Shubham I will try to use it somewhere and if i got any issue i can ping u